# Sencha Touch: function call on view creation

Tags: javascript, extjs, sencha-touch-2

When adding a view to viewport, is there a method I can set in the controller for that view to automatically call a function? I'm looking for something similar to the init function which is called at start. I apologize if its somewhere in the documentation but I cant seem to find anything on it.

Answer (score 0):

All containers have the initialize event which seems to be what you want...

```
{
xtype: 'container',
...
listeners:{
initialize: function(){

}
}
```

Hope it helps you can also use the painted event to call a function every time the view is showed

Comment: Actually, the initialize is called when the view is created, not necessarily added to the Viewport.

Comment: @jakerella: Yes but why would you create a view not add it to the viewport ?

Comment: @TDeBailleul It's not that you would create it and not add it to the Viewport, it's that you may create it at one point in time, then add it at another - in which case the initialize listener would get called not when the view was added, but at some other point. Also, views can be added an removed, thus, according to the OP's question, this answer wouldn't work since the function would not execute when desired.

Comment: i would create a view & add it to viewport sometime later in the future...Exactly initialize would be called before i show the view... There are some scenarios where i wanted that in my app(to initialize certain objects before view gets shown)...

Answer (score -1):

"adding a view to viewport" is kind of a vague situation. Obviously, if you are adding the view manually (by `Ext.Viewport.add({ ... });`) then you can just call a method directly afterward. If, however, the view is created elsewhere and added to the Viewport at some future point, then you might want the [`painted` event](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-1/#!/api/Ext.Viewport-event-painted) (or [`activate`](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-1/#!/api/Ext.Panel-event-activate)) - but be careful, this will fire *any time* the view is rendered, not just the first time. You could also put a listener straight on the `Ext.Viewport` and listen for the [`add` event](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-1/#!/api/Ext.Viewport-event-add), then you would need to need to investigate what view was added exactly. In any case, here's an example listener:

```
config: {
  ...
  listeners: {
    painted: function(){
      // handle the event
    }
  },
  ...
}
```

Comment: there is nothing wrong with this answer .. don't know why it has been downvoted